# Cross Tab using conditional sub-populations

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I am learning how to use the `pandas` python library. I am attempting a problem that is probably not the easiest thing given no prior experience with `pandas` nor any statistical language such as `Stata`.

Suppose I have a data set from a query about people's feelings toward pies and cakes. Most of the questions I have asked are of the form:

> "Do you prefer pies over cakes?" or "Would you vote for a cherry pie for President of the United states in 2020?"

These lead to "Yes" or "No" answers.

Suppose I have `1000` people that have responded but they have some distinctions that matter to my upcoming analysis such as `Gender`, `Eye-Color`, and `primary-hand-use` (right/left/ambidextrous). Also suppose I have hundreds of these distinctions and that eventually I want to compare them all against the same question.

Now, from my `cake-pie.DTA` file I can run:

```
frame = pandas.read_stata("cake-pie.DTA")
answers = ["Yes", "No"]
pandas.crosstab(frame["Question_1", frame["Eye_Color"]], answers, normalize="columns")
```

And this will give me the following:

```
col_0          yes
col_1           no
Question_1 eye_color
Yes  Blue  0.1500
     Hazel 0.050
     Brown 0.2100
     Green 0.050
No   Blue  0.2850
     Hazel 0.0000
     Brown 0.2450
     Green 0.010
```

However, my 1000 people that have responded are not made of equal proportions of each eye color. Perhaps my population looks like:

```
Blue  435 (43.5%)
Hazel  50 (5.0%)
Brown 455 (45.5%)
Green  60 (6.0%)
```

The information I'd like to have output is not an estimation of Probability of GREEN & YES but rather, probability of Yes | GREEN (probability of Yes given Green eyes.)

I realize I can manually divide by the subpopulation total to get that answer but I'm not sure how to divide by the pandas `Series` data that is my eye-color table above to do that in a single cross-tab.

Comment: You added a 0 for Hazel and Green.

Comment: @TedPetrou Urgh, my brain is hurting. Could you edit my question on my behalf with what actually adds up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame looks like the image below you pivot it by unstacking and then dividing each row by its row total.

[image]

```
df1 = df.unstack(0)
df1.div(df1.sum(1), axis=0)

      eye_color          
             No       Yes
Blue   0.655172  0.344828
Brown  0.538462  0.461538
Green  0.166667  0.833333
Hazel  0.000000  1.000000
```

More explanation. `unstack(0)` pivots the outer most level (the levels are zero indexed starting from the left) of the index to a column so you get the following frame.

[image]

`.sum(1)` sums each row. The default is so sum down the columns (axis=0). Then we have to be tricky and use `.div` with axis=0 to to divide by aligning only the index values.

Comment: This appears to work quite well. Could you explain how each magic number is being used here?  I will need to understand that to extend this to more complicated situations.

Comment: Explanation added. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you.